# How to go to site with selenium by pressing button on tkinter window (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, tkinter

I made working Instagram bot on python, but can't make make interface for it and don't know how to connect buttons with functions(tkinter)

I tried to look for some information in Google but didn't understand anything.

```
import sys
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
liked = 0

login = input('Your login   :') 
passwd= input('Your password:') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\path\chromedriver.exe')
hashtag_list = ['travelblog', 'travelblogger', 'traveler']
tag = -1
followed = 0
print(len(hashtag_list))
div = ['div[1]','div[2]','div[3]']
#вход
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher') 
login_form = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
login_form.send_keys(login)
login_from = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
login_from.send_keys(passwd)
login_form.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#Отключить уведомления
time.sleep(3)
notifications = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='aOOlW   HoLwm ']")
notifications.click()
#Лайкать первые 3 поста по тегу

#переход по хештегу
while liked<= 900: 
    for i in range(len(hashtag_list)):

        tag +=1

        driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'+ hashtag_list[tag]+'/')
        time.sleep(2)
        likes = 0
    #Зайти на пост поставить лайк выйти...
        for i in range(1,3):
            wait = random.randint(5,15)
            wait1 = random.randint(1,5)
            #открыть пост
            npost = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/'+div[likes]+'/a/div[1]/div[2]')
            npost.click()
            time.sleep(wait)
            wait = random.randint(5,15)
            wait1 = random.randint(1,5)
            #лайк
            like = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button/span')
            like.click()
            liked+=1
            time.sleep(wait)
            wait = random.randint(5,15)
            wait1 = random.randint(1,5)
            print(liked)
            #подписаться
            follow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button') 
            follow.click()
            time.sleep(wait)
            wait = random.randint(5,15)
            wait1 = random.randint(1,5)
            #unfollow
            unfollow1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button')
            unfollow1.click()
            time.sleep(wait1)
            unfollow2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/button[1]')
            unfollow2.click()
            time.sleep(wait1)
            wait = random.randint(5,15)
            wait1 = random.randint(1,5)
            #закрыть пост
            close = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/button[1]')
            close.click()
            time.sleep(wait1)
            wait = random.randint(5,15)
            wait1 = random.randint(1,5)
            likes+=1

    print(liked)
```

There are no errors but I don't know how to connect it with tkinter and how to make it shorter.

Comment: Have you studied how to use selenium? It doesn't look like you've opened a browser anywhere in your code. Opening a browser is the first thing any selenium tutorial will teach you.

Comment: first create script which can do it without tkinter. Next put it in function and assign function to button. But Selenium may need long time to do get data so it may freeze tkinter window - you may have to use thread to run Selenium.

Comment: what functions do you mean ? I don't see any function in your code. Or maybe you means Selenium's function like find_element_by_XXX ? First split your code into functions and create script which use these function without tkinter.

Answer (score 2):

Minimal example with buttons which open and close Selenium window.

Because Selenium need some time to open browser's windows so tkinter's window freeze for this time.

```
import tkinter as tk
import selenium.webdriver

# --- functions ---

def on_open():
    global driver

    if not driver:
        driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
        url = e.get()
        driver.get(url)

def on_close():
    global driver

    if driver:
        driver.close()
        driver = None

# --- main ---

driver = None

root  = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.insert('end', 'https://stackoverflow.com')

b = tk.Button(root, text='Selenium Open', command=on_open)
b.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text='Selenium Close', command=on_close)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Brilliant little app! Thank you @furas.